# how to pass functions through React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React `<App>` component with inside this structure:

```js
{/*

INSIDE <APP>

        <BreadCrumb>
                <Chip/>
                <Chip/>
                <Chip/>
                    ...
         <BreadCrumb/>

        <CardContainer>
                <Card/>  // just a clickable image 
                <Card/>
                <Card/>
                    ...
                <Button/>
        <CardContainer/>

 */}
```

I need a click on `<Card>` to activate a `<Button>` function, and this function should change the state of `<App>` as "activate" I mean that when I click on a `<Card>` the `<Button>` becomes clickable.

I have some problems to understand how pass function parents to children and set the state of a parent from inside a child.
this is my App component

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 1
    }

  }
    submitChoice() {   
      this.setState({activeIndex : this.state.activeIndex ++});    
    }
 }

       render() {
            return (
                 <Button onClick = {this.submitChoice})/>
                }
```

and this is the Button

```
class Button extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(

            <button   

                onClick = {() => this.props.onClick()}
                className="button">

                Continua

            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

when i click on the button i receve this error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeIndex' of undefined

Comment: They pass exactly like variables, eg `<Card handleClick={this.handleClick}/>`

Comment: You can pass in functions as properties to children. So, you could do something like this: `<Card onClick={enableButton} />`, where enableButton is a function defined in your current scope (eg: `enableButton = () => setState({buttonEnabled: true})`)

Answer (score 1):

Use a property of the "Card" component to pass your callback function:

```
const Card = ({ onClick, id }) => {
  const triggerClick = () => {
    onClick(id);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={triggerClick}>Click the card</div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
 const cardClicked = id => {
   console.log(`Card with id ${id} was clicked`);
   //Modify App state here
 };

 return (
   <CardContainer>
     <Card onClick={cardClicked} id="card-1"/>
     <Card onClick={cardClicked} id="card-2"/>
   </CardContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: In the example above you can also see how to call to the callback function using different arguments depending of the clicked card, but if you don't need it, you could simplify it by simply returning `<div onClick={onClick}>Card content</div>` in the Card component.